# how a format indication like "dd-mm-yyyy" will appear in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am using a date picker which is working well. But i need an indication format like "dd-mm-yyyy" in order to give user an information on how date format is. I am posting for better understanding.

[image]

In the above you can see there is a format indicated like "DD/MM/YY". How to get that printed format in a textbox. I am posting the code i did

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
  </script>
 <style type="text/css">
        .search_textbx
{
 background-image:url('/SalesPropeller/calendar.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:right;  

}

        </style>
```

and in `<body>` tag

```
 <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="search_textbx" size="15" readonly="readonly"/>
```

After compiling the above what i get is like this

[image]

No date format indication in the text box. 
So how to get that indication?? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you need a placeholder attribute:

```
 <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="search_textbx" size="15" readonly="readonly" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/>
```

The placeholder attribute tells the browser to put some sample text (whatever the placeholder value is) in an input as a suggestion to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one specific for your code:

var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();

Comment: More general info available here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate